# Where can I find .curlrc file on UBUNTU?

Tags: linux, curl

Where can i find the .curlrc file? I have tried $HOME/ and echo $CURL_HOME gives me a blank line. I have also tried find . -name ".curlrc" in $HOME. No results.

Please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
updatedb && locate curlrc
```

make sure you run this command as root

or you could...

```
nano ~/.curlrc
```

This is where it should be.

I do believe by default though, there is no curlrc file. You might have to create your own

Comment: Yes, I needed to create one. I expected it by default. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try,

`find / -name .curlrc`

this will output all .curlrc files and you can choose whichever is required.